# Why the string match condition always gives false?

Tags: java, string, if-statement

I am newbie in Java. Was looking at the below condition. The Type always return String but the condition always returns false. If I do direct "Test" == "Test" then it matches. And output for both the words are Test.

Can some one please let me know why it is false?

Thanks.

```
 public static void main(String []args){
    
    String word = "Test";
    
    System.out.println((word.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + word.substring(1)).getClass().getName());
    System.out.println(word.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + word.substring(1));
    System.out.println(word.getClass().getName());
    System.out.println(word);
    if(word.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + word.substring(1) == word)
    {
        System.out.println("t");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("f");
    }
    
 }
```

Comment: Use `.equals` to compare objects, not `==`.

Comment: @luk2302 Ok String is a class and hence it returns object. So object for both  will not match, hence it returns false? Is my understanding right?